# Giving a piggyback, you say: 'get on','climb on' or 'climb up'?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is it correct to say 'get on' to someone you want to carry on your back? Or 'climb' will be more suitable?

Comment: That Depends On The Context™

Comment: Whatever suits the occasion.

Answer (score 1):

"Get on" is probably most apt. When giving someone a piggy back ride, they rarely climb up your body. Although climb could be used more figuratively to exaggerate the motion of getting on. It also reinforces the namesake of a piggy back ride because you often climb onto or mount a horse.

Comment: I think it depends on the relative height of the piggy-backer and piggy-backed, and whether the former is standing or not. Some increase in elevation may be necessary, resulting in 'get up' potentially fitting better.